# Access keys for Local Machine from Microsoft KSP

Tags: c++, cng, microsoft-key-storage-provider

The below powershell command correctly lists all the keys for my local machine store:

```
certutil -csp "Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider" -key
```

However, I am not able to do the same through C++ code using NCryptOpenStorageProvider and NCryptOpenKey APIs. I suspect that NCryptOpenStorageProvider is not giving me the list that includes Local Machine keys. My API usage is as below:

```
NCryptOpenStorageProvider(&prov, MS_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER, 0);
NCryptOpenKey(prov, &keyHandle, pCryptKeyProvInfo->pwszContainerName, 0, NCRYPT_MACHINE_KEY_FLAG);
```

Can someone provide a clue on this?
Thanks in advance.

Additional info:
`certutil -csp "Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider" -key` returns NULL when run normally, but gives the proper list of keys only when run with Admin privilge.
So, I assume it has something to do with privileges.
Can someone suggest where I can update the privileges for my KSP corresponding to Local Machine?